# error lnk2038: mismatch detected for '_msc_ver'

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++

I upgrade my Microsoft visual studio to 2015 version , QT is 4.8.3 version , while building a sample project am Getting this error

```
error lnk2038: mismatch detected for '_msc_ver': value '1600' doesn't match value '1900'
```

am struck here , any help is appreciated , Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try clean rebuild of the project.

Comment: Tried but no use , i think qt 4.8.3  version  not supports to visual studio 2015

Answer (score 2):

This is likely caused by the fact that you Qt version was built with MSVC 2008 (1600) which is incompatible with MSVC 2015 (1900) which you are trying to use.

Sadly there is no official Qt 4 builds for any MSVC version after 2010.

To solve your issue you can:

- Stay with MSVC 2008 or MSVC 2010 and use one of the Qt 4 official builds.
- Make your own Qt build using MSVC 2015 (note that 2015 and 2017 are compatible).
- Switch to Qt 5 and use an official Qt build (2013, 2015 and 2017 builds are available).

*Note: if you stick to Qt 4, use at least the latest patch release: 4.8.7 which is forward and backward compatible with all Qt 4.8.x releases. But as Qt 4 is not supported anymore, it would be even better if you switch to Qt 5. The latest release Qt 5.9 is an LTS version and it will have bug fix updates for 3 years.*